# React PropTypes isRequired warning with cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[React-Numpad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-numpad) is a libarary that works following HoC. There are  NumPad and StaticWrapper components (folder: lib/components) that renders children of type: KeyPad, Calendar and Appointment (folder: lib/elements).

While running tests I get some warnings on required props undefined that are initialized in NumPad and StaticWrapper.

The props: confirm, update; are marked as required in children components.

**Parent component:**

https://github.com/gpietro/react-numpad/blob/v5.0.0-beta.14/lib/components/StaticWrapper.js#L30

**Child component:**

https://github.com/gpietro/react-numpad/blob/v5.0.0-beta.14/lib/elements/KeyPad.js#L172

**Tests giving warning**

[https://github.com/gpietro/react-numpad/blob/v5.0.0-beta.14/lib/**tests**/useKeyboardTest.js#L10](https://github.com/gpietro/react-numpad/blob/v5.0.0-beta.14/lib/__tests__/useKeyboardTest.js#L10)

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I found the answer on a react repository [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6653).

> **Dan Abramov**
>
> Yes, this is expected because elements are checked at the creation
>   time. So when you write , it turns into a
>   React.createElement() call, and the props are validated.
>
> When you rely on cloneElement() to specify required props, our
>   recommendation is to use defaultProps in your component for sensible
>   fallbacks, e.g.
>
> MyComponent.defaultProps = {   onSubmit: () => {} }